# How to get token amounts in a Uniswap Liquidity pool?

Tags: go-ethereum, uniswap

I've searched and found a couple examples, but they don't seem to work anymore with the uniswap API.

I'm looking to get the liquidity amounts of 2 tokens in a uniswap pool, and found through the documentation reserve0 and reserve1, but when I access these propteries, they dont produce a number on the pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than going to the contracts themselves, using the [Uniswap v2 SubGraph](https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v2), the query:

```
{
  pairs {
    id, 
    reserve0,
    reserve1
  }
}
```

...correctly returns the data for all pairs:

```
{
  "data": {
    "pairs": [
      {
        "id": "0x00004ee988665cdda9a1080d5792cecd16dc1220",
        "reserve0": "199.713907280830191521",
        "reserve1": "40.523599"
      },
      {
        "id": "0x0000871c95bb027c90089f4926fd1ba82cdd9a8b",
        "reserve0": "0.000000000000007155",
        "reserve1": "0.000000000000000141"
      },
      {
        "id": "0x00031554ee74e4a6d497677e5152d94c3dbe5f46",
        "reserve0": "0.000000000000020727",
        "reserve1": "0.000183887381173668"
      },
      .....
```

Change the query for the pair(s) you're interested in.

Comment: Glad it worked! :-)

Comment: What do exactly reserve1 and reserve0 stand for? Can I calculate the circulating supply of the token or market cap from this? or price?@RichardHorrocks

Comment: Hi @Mugetsu - `reserve0` and `reserve1` are the amounts of two tokens in a particular Uniswap liquidity pool. You can calculate the price _on Uniswap_ using other available values, but this may or may not reflect the price in other markets (e.g. centralised exchanges). You can't work out the market cap or circulating supply from these values - they only represent what is available in this Uniswap liquidity pool (which might only be a small fraction of the overall circulating supply).

Comment: Thank you for the response @RichardHorrocks! I find your account and all the questions/answers very informative. Just going through them <3. Could you possibly point me how I could find out the market cap and current circulating supply of the given token?

Comment: You're welcome :-) For the market cap and circulating supply, you could use an offchain API, like Coingecko's. For example, for the PancakeSwap token (CAKE), the API data has `market_cap` and `circulating_supply` fields (https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/pancakeswap-token)

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the suggestion but I'm looking for something real-time from blockchain rather than relying on some 3rd party. Actually, I found this post which gives me what I was looking for :) https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99541/how-to-calculate-the-amount-of-dead-tokens
 Thank you anyway! Keep the good work.

Comment: Okay, glad you found what you were after :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found to get the total liquidity in a pool is to call the balanceOf(address) function on the token contracts, passing in the address of the pool.

Comment: Any method to get the liquidity owned by a specific address?

Comment: Yes. The NonfungiblePositionManager contract has balanceOf() to tell you how many positions an address holds, tokenOfOwnerByIndex() gives the id for each, and positions() give the details. You need the UniSwap SDK to convert the results into something meaningful.