# How to calculate the amount of dead tokens?

Tags: decentralized-exchange

Let's take [Saturna](https://bscscan.com/address/0x1e446CbEa52BAdeB614FBe4Ab7610F737995fB44) as an example.

The contract says that the total supply is `1000000000000000000000000`. Meanwhile, [Bogged](https://charts.bogged.finance/?token=0x1e446CbEa52BAdeB614FBe4Ab7610F737995fB44) shows that:

- token price is USD 0.00000000922018, and
- market cap is USD 6,152,615

I would expect that `supply x token price = market cap`, however, that is not the case:

```
1000000000000000000000000
*
0.00000000927378
=
9,273,780,000,000,000
```

I suspect that the reason for this is that `total supply != circulating supply`.

How do I get `total supply - burned tokens`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each contract can have it's own "dead" or "burn" address.

1. Saturna uses "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead" address for that, accounting for 33% of the total supply, according to BSCScan [1]:

```
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead => 333,964,566,341,675.193475472
```

2. On your calculation, keep in mind the "decimals" field on the token. Saturna has 9 decimal fields. You can look for "decimals" on the token page. So the total supply is actually:

```
1000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000(.000000000) <= 9 of those zeroes represent decimals
```

Let's do the calculation again, taking into consideration the two pieces of information above:

```
(1000000000000000.000000000 - 333964566341675.193475472)* 0.00000000927378

= 6,176,666.083951899
```

Any further questions?

[1] https://bscscan.com/token/0x1e446CbEa52BAdeB614FBe4Ab7610F737995fB44#balances

Comment: Thanks! I was able to to get the burned amount using `balanceOf` and then, as you mentioned, by deducting it and dividing by 10^9, I got the expected amount. Apart from `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead` and `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, are there any other "conventional" addresses that are used for burning tokens?

Comment: When I am looking at the Saturna contract, I don't see `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead` mentioned anywhere. Where is that address coming from?

Comment: The 0x0…dead address is the #1 on the Holders tab of the token page: https://bscscan.com/token/0x1e446CbEa52BAdeB614FBe4Ab7610F737995fB44#balances